# Getting data from Firebase taking lot of time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to store data fro my application. I just have 4 users now. And just querying them is taking more than 35 secs on average. What may be the issue ? Is this because of firebase Or I am not writing the code properly somewhere? Any alternative to quicken up the process ? I am just reading the posts of a specific user from the database in a fragment and displaying in recyclerView . Below is my code.

Firebase databse structure

```
Users: { 
            7828272892 : {
                 name: xyz, 
                 gender: male,
                 phoneNo: 7828272892
                 Posts: {
                     SomeKey1: {
                         content: "This is post 1", Var2: "kkk"} }},
            7924272894 : {name: abc, gender: male, phoneNo: 7924272894} 
        }
```

Code of the fragment class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.view.View.GONE;

public class MyWallFragment extends Fragment {
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private List<Post> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressBar pgsBar;
    private RecyclerViewAdapterMyWall rcAdapter;


    public MyWallFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_wall, container, false);

        final RecyclerView rView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        pgsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pBar);

        rView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterMyWall(allItems);
        rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
        rView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        String myNumber = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
        String phnNo = myNumber;
        if (phnNo.length()>10) {
            phnNo = phnNo.substring(phnNo.length()-10);
        }

        databaseReference.child("Users").child(phnNo).child("Posts").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                allItems = new ArrayList<Post>();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String content = postSnapshot.child("content").getValue().toString();
                    Post post = new Post("x","Y", content);
                    allItems.add(post);
                    rcAdapter.addItem(post);
                }

                pgsBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say that it takes 35 seconds.. is that 35 seconds for the data to appear on the users screen, or 35 seconds until you actually retrieve the data from the database (if you put a breakpoint in your code and timed it)

Comment: Can you ' Log.d("TIMER",Calendar.getInstance().getTime()+"")' just before calling databaseReference.child("Users")...... and inside onDataChanged()? And let us know the results

Comment: @mark922  The time gap between both the logs is around 30 sec.